# Set a circle as the default tab in a Google Plus profile

Tags: google-plus

When I click Myname+ on a Google site, it loads the G+ profile with the "All" tab enabled by default. That means, it shows updates from all streams (all the circles I have created more or less).

I want to change it to show the "Family" circle by default. How can I change it?

Comment: Google+ doesn't seem to provide a setting for this but it should be possible to do this inside the browser. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the "All" tab to only view the "Family" circle (or any other set of circles you want).

To do this:

1. View the stream of each other circle by selecting that circle.
2. In the upper right hand corner above the stream, there is a slider that selects the volume. Set the volume all the way down (to the left).
3. Repeat this for each of the circles you do NOT want in your main stream.
4. For your "Family" circle, move the volume all the way up (to the right) to make sure you get all of the posts from that circle.

The volume slider only controls what shows up in the main stream - you can still view all the posts in each circle by visiting that circle.

Answer (score 0):

There is a user script for this: [1](http://wittman.org/google-plus-extensions/#default-circle). Opera and Chrome will support it natively, if you use a different browser you will have to install an extension (For Firefox: [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/))

Comment: I am using Opera 12, and can't install the script. I clicked on install link and the Opera opens the java scirpt code file

Comment: You have to enable user scripts in the preferences first. [Here](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/using/) is how to do it.

Comment: I have enabled that, restarted my opera, unfortunately not working :(